# Casting in RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

May I know which one is better?
The first one we set the textView as TextView and we inflate the view and cast it to TextView type

The second one we set the textView as View type and we inflate it as type View

```
    class MyViewHolder(val textView: TextView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(textView)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        val textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false) as TextView
        return MyViewHolder(textView)
    }
```

or

```
     class MyViewHolder(val textView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(textView)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        val textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(textView)
    }
```

Comment: You should use `View`, when there is a change in the layout (You decide to replace `TextView` by other kind) you don't need to change the cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everything, it depends on more conditions. If you are using view holder like this, I mean, not using custom XML, it is better to use View, because if in any place you don't need any specific TextView property, then there is no point of using TextView.

But! If you want to use your custom XML file and use this view inside ViewHolder as TextView, then it should TextView since the beginning.